# Horizontally and Vertically center text for TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, text, textview

How do I center the text horizontally and vertically for a TextView in Android?
How do I center the alignment of a TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linear Layouts use

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

In Relative Layouts

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Above Code will center the textView in layout
To center the text in TextView

```
android:textAlignment="center"
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: It centers TextView not its text.

Answer (score 0):

add this property for textview in xml

```
textview<android:height="yourheight"
android:width="yourwidth"
android:gravity="center">
```

your width size should be less than the  parent container's width size

Comment: totally agree..but `your width size should match the parent container's width size` is not necessary.

Comment: not perfect..let me try `height and width must not be wrap-content or it must be greater than wrap-content`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have declared the height and width.  If you used wrap_content, then the textview is just big enough in that direction to hold the text, so the gravity attribute will not apply. android:gravity affects the location of the text Within the space allocated for the textview.  layout_xx attributes affect the location of the view within it's parent.

SO if you set the size of the textview, then use gravity to position the text within the textview area, if you used wrap_content, then use the layout_xx attributes to position the textview within it's parent